# Spring RestTemplate: how to define the parameter type in a generic class

Tags: java, spring, generics, resttemplate

I'm writing a generic REST client to be used with different types of DTOs.

```
public abstract class GenericClient<DTO> {
  private final Class<DTO> dtoClass;
  ... ctor which sets dtoClass ...

  public DTO getOne(String id) {
    ...
    URI uri = ...
    ResponseEntity<DTO> exchange = getRestTemplate()
      .exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, dtoClass);
    return exchange.getBody(); // works
  }

  public List<DTO> findAll() {
    ...
    URI uri = ...
    ResponseEntity<List<DTO>> exchange = getRestTemplate()
      .exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<DTO>() {});
    return exchange.getBody(); // fails with ClassCastException
  }
}
```

This is implemented by several concrete clients like this

```
public class OneActualDTOClient extends GenericClient<OneActualDTO> {
  public OneActualDTOClient(){
    super(OneActualDTO.class);
  }
}
```

This compiles, and the `getOne` method works fine. But for `findAll`, at runtime, the type parameter DTO is not available, so the `exchange` method cannot deserialize the incoming JSON (as far as I understand).

As you see, I pass the concrete DTO class (as a `Class<DTO>`) to use with exchange for single elementes (`getOne`).

How should I pass the ParameterizedTypeReference to the `exchange` method, so that at runtime it knows to return as `List<OneActualDTO>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution, which is to override the `getType` method of `ParameterizedTypeReference` returning a custom made `ParameterizedType` like this:

```
public abstract class GenericClient<DTO> {
  private final Class<DTO> dtoClass;
  ... ctor which sets dtoClass ...


  public List<DTO> findAll() {
    ...
    URI uri = ...
    ResponseEntity<List<DTO>> exchange = getRestTemplate()
      .exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<DTO>() {
        @Override
        public Type getType() {
            return new ParameterizedType() {
                @Override
                public Type getRawType() {
                    return List.class;
                }

                @Override
                public Type getOwnerType() {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
                    return new Type[]{dtoClass};
                }
            };
        });
    return exchange.getBody(); // OK
  }
}
```